# Convention: Which model should I put hasOne and belongsTo method

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have two models in a Laravel App, Contact and Address which is related to each other.

contacts fields: [id, name]
addresses fields: [id, address, contact_id]

In the Contact model, I added :

```php
public function address(){
    return $this->hasOne(Address::class);
}
```

In the Address model, I added :

```php
public function contact(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Contact::class);
}
```

I was wondering if it would be ok to interchange the hasOne and belongsTo on the functions, or would it be against any convention that exists.

Like this
contacts fields: [id, name, address_id]
addresses fields: [id, address]

The reason I am asking this is because I want to create a factory that creates the data on the related tables.

So I would like to generated the seeds of other related tables of contacts like address, role, etc. and get the id during create.

```php
$factory->define(App\Contact::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'address_id' => factory(App\Address::class)->create()->id,
        'other_detail_id' => factory(App\OtherDetail::class)->create()->id
    ];
});
```

Comment: Your current definition is okay, don't do it the other way because it will not work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, you can still create seeder using factory with current implementation i.e.

```
$contacts = factory(App\Contact::class, 100)
->create()
->each(function($contact){
    $contact->address()->save(factory(App\Address::class)->make());
}
```

This code will be placed in seeder of yours, and you will have factories defined for both Contact & Address, and seeder will use the eager relation to do that.

Comment: if he uses his factory definition, it will work 100%, if he uses yours, it will not work, because you are using `make` instead of `create`. Make will only create but not save, and create will save it. I know you are saving it, that is why you are using `make`, but you are doing something it is 100% fixed in his factory.

Comment: btw, you relation would be

public function address(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Address::class);
}

in the contact.php model

Comment: @matiaslauriti please review again, i am also using the save() method on relation, which will actually create the child entry in table as well.

Secondly, his question was to follow convention, i gave solution in which he don't have to change the relation, he can still use factory with mentioned relation he did in start of his question.

contacts fields: [id, name] addresses fields: [id, address, contact_id]

his factory will not work with mentioned above structure.

Comment: In my address factory, I created the contact record and used its id in the contact_id. Then I added factory(App\Address::class, 10)->create() in the DatabaseSeeder. The contact is then created during the creation of the address record. What I want is factory(App\Contact::class, 10)->create() and create the address while the contact is being created. This is because I also have other tables that are related to the contacts. I want to seed them using contact not the other way around.

Comment: @lordango

My mentioned above solution will create the contacts & addresses along with it and you don't have to put "address_id" in contacts table for this. In this way you can use contact table with other relations/seeders as well.

Comment: Your mentioned worked! I wonder if there is a way that I only have to write, factory(App\Contact::class, 100)->create(); in the DatabaseSeeder.php and contact and addresses will be created.